# Safety of passing integers between Python and Rust

Tags: python, rust, ctypes, integer-overflow

### Is This Safe?

Suppose I wanted to call some **Rust** code from within **Python**. Suppose my `lib.rs` looks something like this:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn add(left: i32, right: i32) -> i32 {
    return left+right;
}
```

And supposed I called this code from Python using `ctypes` like this:

```py
import ctypes

def rust_add(left, right):
    rust_lib = ctypes.CDLL("path/to/the/so/file")
    return rust_lib.add(left, right)
```

Then **is the above safe?**

### An Anticipated Snag: Integer Overflow

#### Overflow in the Inputs

One issue which even I - with my extremely tenuous grasp of Rust - can foresee is **integer overflow**. I imagine that, if either `left` or `right` was greater than 2^32, that would cause bad things to happen: either Rust would hit a run-time error (most likely), or it would just return silly answers (worst case). Would some type-checking in the Python, perhaps using NumPy's `uint32`, be sufficient to prevent this issue?

#### Overflow in the Workings

This one is more insidious: suppose I ask, from Python, my Rust function to add (2^32)-1 and  (2^32)-2. There shouldn't be any immediate overflow, but there will be once we add the two numbers together. As I understand it, on hitting such an overflow, Rust will panic in debug mode but try its best to soldier on in release mode.

### Summary

- Is there any well-known practice for smoothing out the difficulties that arise when passing integers between a dynamic-width language, such as Python, and a fixed-width one, such as Rust, other than thorough testing?
- Are there any issues with passing integers between Rust and Python *apart from* integer overflow?

Comment: Recommend using a safe library like [PyO3](https://pyo3.rs/) for this kind of thing.

Comment: Panic across FFI boundary is UB, so addition overflow is not OK.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I take it that UB = undefined behaviour, but what's FFI?

Comment: @TomHosker: Foreign Function Interface. How different languages talk to each other (usually by reducing to the lowest common denominator, C function call conventions, but often wrapped in ways to try and preserve the feel of the calling language).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: could you provide a reference for why that would by UB? I was under the impression that it would just abort the process: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#panic-can-be-stopped-at-an-abi-boundary

Comment: @ChrisB Currently it aborts, but it is UB and it is planned to switch to exploiting that UB somewhere (with being able to use the `C-unwind` ABI to unwind). See https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html#behavior-considered-undefined, "Calling a function with the wrong call ABI or unwinding from a function with the wrong unwind ABI.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `ctypes` will convert integer parameters and function return values to it's [`c_int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_int) type,
whose size is dependant on the platform. Values exceeding this size will be truncated. If `c_int` happens to not be 32 bits, that would be lead to undefined behavior in the Rust sense (you end up calling the rust function with an incorrect calling convention). That is probably not what you would want in this case. (Admittedly, `c_int` **is** 32 bits on most common desktop plattforms).

I still recommend the following python code:

```py
_rust_lib = ctypes.CDLL("path/to/the/so/file")
_rust_add = _rust_lib.add
_rust_add.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int32, ctypes.c_int32]
_rust_add.restype = ctypes.c_int32

def rust_add(left, right):
    return _rust_add(left, right)
```

This way, `ctypes` will convert arguments and return types to the correct integer type regardless of the plattform.

It will still truncate larger integers and throw an exception for other python types though. If you want to have a different way of handling those cases you would have to do that yourself.
For more details on how type conversions are handled by `ctypes` I recommend their excellent [documentation](https://svn.python.org/projects/ctypes/trunk/ctypes/docs/manual/tutorial.html).

---

If you just want to make sure that the passed in values are sane, and get some kind of exception in all other cases, you could write a simple function like this:

```py
def sanitize_i32(v):
    # alternatively throw some exception
    assert isinstance(v, int)
    assert v >= -2**31 and v < 2**31
    return v

def rust_add(left, right):
    return _rust_add(sanitize_i32(left), sanitize_i32(right))
```

---

Regarding overflows on the Rust side: those will follow Rust's usual
[integer overflow rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#integer-overflow) (panic in debug, two's complement wrap in release).
If that's not what you want, code some other logic.

Comment: Like this answer a lot. Two follow-up questions: (1) Any snags extending your approach to `i32`, `i64`, `i128` and possibly some more exotic integer types, provided `ctypes` has an equivalent? Are you aware of any other type-related hazards with what I'm doing (as per my second summary bullet point)?

Comment: I edited to remove the unnecessary wrapping around the definition of `rust_add` (a wrapping function that reloads and reparameterizes the underlying function on every call seems rather silly when the work it does could *create* the unwrapped function directly and save a lot of hassle). Hope that doesn't conflict with your intent. I left the sanitizing version unchanged, but if that were a concern, I'd usually just name the underlying function `_rust_add` loaded once globally, with `rust_add` (the sanitizing wrapper) calling it.

Comment: @TomHosker: There are no issues with this approach for `i64`.
As long as you pass valid integers (the `sanitize` function is sufficient for enforcing all necessary invariants), you're good to go. `ctypes` does not have an `i128` datatype though, so you would be out of luck there and would have to pass e.g. 2 `u64`s and reassemble on the rust side.

Comment: You could avoid the wrapper even in the sanitizing case, but it would involve implementing validating classes [following the rules for `argtypes`, via a `from_param` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.argtypes), and that's not needed unless performance is really critical.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Hm, I left that out because I thought it made it unneccessarily complicated, but you're probably right, this is better for copy pasting purposes :).