# When is a panic on a Rust FFI boundary Undefined Behavior?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, ffi

The [rustnomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#panic-can-be-stopped-at-an-abi-boundary) contains the following example:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
extern "C" fn assert_nonzero(input: u32) {
    assert!(input != 0)
}
```

> If `assert_nonzero` is called with the argument `0`, the runtime is guaranteed to (safely) abort the process, whether or not compiled with `panic=abort`.

---

The [Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html#behavior-considered-undefined) on the other hand claims that:

> Behavior considered undefined: [...] Calling a function with the wrong call ABI or unwinding from a function with the wrong unwind ABI.

---

These two statements seem contradictory to me. `assert_nonzero` has the `C` ABI, but unwinds from a Rust panic. So is that *guaranteed to (safely) abort*, or *UB*? It can't be both.

Chayim Friedman kindly suggested on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77876062/safety-of-passing-integers-between-python-and-rust/77876436#77876436) that this is indeed UB.

So is the Rustnomicon simply outdated, or am I misunderstanding something?

More generally: **Exactly when is a Rust panic crossing an FFI boundary considered Undefined Behavior?**

Comment: Yeah, it unwinds from the assert. which (presumably) does not have "wrong unwind ABI". I don't see a contradiction here.

Comment: AFAIKT, this is currently in flux thanks to https://github.com/rust-lang/project-ffi-unwind

Comment: @freakish: I would have assumed that the C ABI is 'wrong' for a Rust panic, no?

Comment: @ChrisB but the panic does not exit the function. It aborts the process. From the external caller it is C ABI. In other words: for the caller there is nothing to unwind, the concept doesn't even exist for him.

Comment: @freakish: You might be right. I guess it depends on what is considered 'unwinding'. I assumed that exiting a function early because of a panic already counts as 'unwinding', but they may be using different definition used here, along the lines of what you are suggesting.

Comment: @ChrisB I don't think I use any special meaning of the word "unwinding". The function never exits early. On panic the entire process is terminated. Thinking in terms of higher level language: its like wrapping body with try{}catch{} that kills the process on exception. With such design the caller does not have to worry about "exceptions", in the sense that the function became exception free. Unwinding becomes irrelevant for the caller. And I believe that the docs simply say that Rust does this unwinding for you on extern "C" functions.

Comment: @freakish: I'm not talking about `panic=abort`, but the default case, which is explicitly included by the rustnomicon. I expect the stack of nested functions to be unwound, `Drop` impls to be executed, and `catch_unwind`s to be respected. Not an immediate abort.

Comment: @ChrisB The "guaranteed to safely abort the process" part means that it won't unwind past the C function call (it might unwind a little bit, or it might abort immediately), even if `panic=unwind` is set. It overrides the panic setting.

Comment: @ChrisB clearly the docs say that this behaviour is valid on extern C functions regardless of panic=unwind setting. Also it does unwind normally, but not beyond the function. It literally is automatic wrapping of C functions with try{...} catch{ abort() } block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the RFC for `-unwind` ABIs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2945-c-unwind-abi.md#changes-to-the-behavior-of-existing-abi-strings):

> ### Changes to the behavior of existing ABI strings
>
> Prior to this RFC, any unwinding operation that crossed an `extern "C"` boundary, either from a `panic!` "escaping" from a Rust function
> defined with `extern "C"` or by entering Rust from another language
> via an entrypoint declared with `extern "C"`, caused undefined
> behavior.
>
> This RFC retains most of that undefined behavior, with one exception:
> with the `panic=unwind` runtime, `panic!` will cause an `abort` if it
> would otherwise "escape" from a function defined with `extern "C"`.
>
> This change will be applied to all ABI strings other than `"Rust"`,
> such as `"system"`.

So it appears that this used to be UB, but after this RFC was accepted, this is no longer UB and guaranteed to abort.

I don't know if we can say that the reference is outdated, since we can say that we just don't unwind (but abort) on panics from `extern "C"` Rust functions.